# Print all listbox items

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to print all of listbox items.

The output should be like this:

```
asd

qweasd

asdkjh
```

but what happens is this:

```
asd

asdqweasd

asdqweasdasdkjh
```

Here is my code.

```
        a = bname.Items;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Book", fontm, Brushes.Black, 20, 170);
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}", item.ToString());
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sb.ToString(), fonta, Brushes.Black, 20, x);
            x += 20;
        }
```

Comment: Stick a breakpoint on your `foreach` and I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StringBuilder` is never cleared at each iteration.. so each time the string is drawn it is drawn with everything that preceded it.

Clearing the `StringBuilder` after each drawing operation is the easiest solution:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString....
sb.Clear() // <-- this
```

However, the *correct* solution would be to drop the `StringBuilder` altogether and just draw the value of the item you're currently iterating over:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(item, ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do sb.Clear() in the end of the loop, it will work.

```
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", item.ToString());
        e.Graphics.DrawString(sb.ToString(), fonta, Brushes.Black, 20, x);
        x += 20;
        sb.Clear();  
    }
```